# ESLint: Assignment to property of function parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, eslint

Given a structure like:

```
products: {
  '123': {
     details: [
        {
           price: 45,
           unitPrice: 0,
           productName: 'apples'
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

And a function,

```
function modifyPriceForApples(coefficient) {
    const products = cloneDeep(vehicleProductSelector.getAllProducts(store.getStore().getState()));
    let appleProduct;

    Object.keys(products).forEach((productId) => {
        const {
            details
        } = vehicleProducts[productId];
        details.forEach((detail) => {
            const {
                price,
                productName
            } = detail;
            if (productName === 'apples') {
                detail.unitPrice = coefficient * detail.price;
                appleProduct = products[productId];
            }
        });
    });
    return appleProduct;
}
```

I am getting linting error: `Assignment to property of function parameter`

How can I resolve that, barring disabling the linting rule?

I keep seeing array destructuring as the answer to this problem, however I'm not too sure what that would look like in practice given that this is a pretty complex structure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of of using `forEach`, use a `map` and act as though arguments provided to a function are immutable.  It's mad that you are doing `details.forEach((detail) => {...});` and then assigning to `detail` with `detail.unitPrice = coefficient * detail.price;`.